# I have uploaded a pdf file and when try to open it on my website it's showing file not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to open a pdf file when I click on my website. The PDF is uploaded from the admin, but it's showing not found 404

view

```
 <div class="entry-content">
   <a target="_blank" href="{{$post->file}}">
      <p style="font-size: 18px;color: #468b10;"> 
         {{ $post->content }}
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
   if (request('file')) {
       $file = request('file');
       $file=$file_name::get($file);
       $file_name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $file->move('uploads/posts', $file_name);
       $data['file'] = 'uploads/posts/'.$file_name;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you saving the file name in your database?

Comment: it's not saving anything, so I am condused

Comment: you seem to be not saving either file name or file path in your database and may be its path issue, is it throwing any error when the file is uploaded?

Comment: Still have same issue, can help?

Comment: I have used the command in controller for show and save pic in public/upload